# Why is HTTP decompression not working with wget and php?

Tags: php, http, compression, wget

A file is hosted at server that delivers gzipped content.

The HTTP response headers are the following:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.5.13
  Date: Fri, 06 Feb 2015 19:18:54 GMT
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Content-Length: 21555
  Last-Modified: Fri, 06 Feb 2015 14:03:41 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  ETag: "54d4c9bd-5433"
  Content-Encoding: gzip
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

The url is:

http://torcache.net/torrent/CC210980B3155B9E7E11479C9057E70591D2C6AE.torrent

When I look at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) for HTTP Compression 
it looks correct.

When I download the url with wget, the file does not get deflated. When I examine it on the disk it is a gzipped file.

```
$ wget -O test1 http://torcache.net/torrent/CC210980B3155B9E7E11479C9057E70591D2C6AE.torrent
...
$ file test1
test1: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix
```

When I gunzip it, it is a bittorrent file.

```
$ gunzip -dc test1 > test2 && file test2
test2: BitTorrent file
```

When I examine the file, when I downloaded it with firefox, it is a Bittorrent file.

```
$ file CC210980B3155B9E7E11479C9057E70591D2C6AE.torrent 
CC210980B3155B9E7E11479C9057E70591D2C6AE.torrent: BitTorrent file
```

I am on the latest Ubuntu 14.10 with all software up to date.

The headers look correct, Firefox correctly inflates the content. Why does wget and php not?

Comment: wget's job is to fetch the specified url and return its contents verbatim. it does that. a browser's job is to fetch a specified and INTERPRET it for human-usage. so it'll automatically ungzip a gzip'd output.

Comment: @MarcB i disagree. the content is the torrent file, not the gzipped version. the gzipped version arises from the compression in the http protocol, which wget should follow, which means decompressing it on the other side. because it is a http client. maby wget sends no accept-encoding header that indicates compression support, and thus is not expecting compression. however the protocol is not followed correctly by either the client or the server.

Comment: yes, but the server unconditionally turned on gzip deflation, even thou you didn't have curl send out the appropriate `accept` header. therefore wget saved exactly what the server sent out - a gzipped data stream. gzip has no way of knowing if what got sent out was an actual .gz file, or some other content that got gzipped on-the-fly for transmission. all it sees is application/octet-stream and content-encoding.

Comment: I agree that the server responding with gzipped content regardless of the accept encoding request header is probably the cause of the problem. But shouldn't wget see the content-type: gzip response header and react accordingly? Well, I used curl in PHP and set curlopt encoding to gzip. That seems to work. But I still think its a little bit weird.

Comment: I want to fetch a file form any url, also from servesr that do not respond gzipped. How can I have a solution that always works? Just get the file behind the url... @AbraCadaver

Comment: like I said, wget's job is to just fetch the data, not interpret it. the content-type and content-encoding and content-disposition headers are irrelevant to wget. it's going to suck down a stream of bytes and write those bytes out to wherever you want.

Comment: This is especially bad in the case of wget -r (recursive fetch), which if wget doesn't decompress the content, how on earth is it going to parse the html to get the links to traverse? It's broken.